# PHP mysqli_fetch_row

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have this line of code:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);
```

and the results are:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => [2] => 2014-02-21 [3] => 13:07:00 [4] => Toronto [5] => New York [6] => 2014-02-25 15:19:41 [7] =>  [8] => 2014-02-20 [9] => Toronto [10] => 2 [11] => New York [12] => 3 )
```

My Question is, how do I get it display the field name like so:

```
[id] => 1 ['isOpen'] => ['date'] => 2014-02-21
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead of [`mysqli_fetch_row()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

Use this

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```